# Get the count of Javascript object in jade from mongoose/node data

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I have a node app which is tied to a mongo database and has routing with express and templates generated by Jade. Using express I am getting a list of all users using the following function:

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    User.find({}, function(err, users) {
        var userMap = {};

        users.forEach(function(user){
            userMap[user._id] = user;
        });

        res.render('page', {
            users : userMap
        })

    });
});
```

In my jade view I can display the users easily using:

```
each user in users
  li= user.username
```

But I also want to get a count of the obj coming back and display that data on the page. I have tried `#{users.size}` and `{users.length}` as well as a few other variations to no avail. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Do I need to add a count method to the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your variable `users` is an object not a array try

```
Object.keys(users).length
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where this needs to go. I tried a few things but none worked.

Comment: If I use `#{users}` I get `[object Object]` where the variable is called in jade

Comment: try #{Object.keys(users).length}